# Vertical center font awesome icon in pure SVG

Tags: html, svg, font-awesome

I have an svg application that uses Font Awesome icons. I'm trying to vertically center a Font Awesome icon inside an SVG circle but I can't get pixel perfect vertical centering. I'm close but the icon is always a bit too high. I don't know what type of icon I might use so I need a generic solution (i.e. I can't hard code it for certain icons).

Here is my code:

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/c3ef28c600.js"></script>
<svg width="200" height="200">
  <g transform="translate(65, 65)">
    <circle r="55" stroke="blue" stroke-width="10" fill="red"></circle>
    <text dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" style="font-family: 'FontAwesome';" fill="white" font-size="65px">&#xf128;</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: For an arbitrary glyph in a font you don't control, there isn't an SVG way to determine the bounding box of the rendered pixels, so you can't get what you're looking for in pure SVG. It is technically possible for a font to implement an enclosing circle glyph that when rendered does the right thing for the other glyphs in the font, but that's something that has to be designed into the font. Maybe FontAwesome even has this , I don't know.

Comment: If I generated the SVG via javascript would it be possible? @PaulDempsey

Comment: Only if you can get the pixel bounding box of the glyph. I don't think that's readily available, but perhaps someone has more up-to-date info than I hae..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it seams like `dominant-baseline="central"` gives a better result. [dominant-baseline - central](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/dominant-baseline#central)

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/c3ef28c600.js"></script>
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 120 120">
  <g transform="translate(60, 60)">
    <circle r="55" stroke="blue" stroke-width="10" fill="red"></circle>
    <text dominant-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle" style="font-family: 'FontAwesome';" fill="white" font-size="100">&#xf128;</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

An alternative could be a monospace font. Here I just gaped one from Google Fonts:

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Azeret+Mono:wght@900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 120 120">
  <g transform="translate(60, 60)">
    <circle r="55" stroke="blue" stroke-width="10" fill="red"></circle>
    <text dominant-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle" style="font-family: 'Azeret Mono', monospace;" fill="white" font-size="100">?</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```